# How to call funtions defined in controller in asp.net core razor pages project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to asp.net core and i am exploring different ways to make api calls to function defined in controller.

I have a basic news controller as below, if i keep only one function in this controller `GetAll()` then i am able to make successful call to api using `https://localhost:44364/api/news`

and when i add other two function then same `https://localhost:44364/api/news` gets error message as below which is quite obvious as i am not making not mentioning function name in my url.

My question is how can i define route for each function so that i can call each of these function by url and from ajax function

**Error**

```
 BookListRazor.Controllers.NewsController.GetSingleNews (BookListRazor)
    BookListRazor.Controllers.NewsController.GetAll (BookListRazor)
    BookListRazor.Controllers.NewsController.GetAllNews (BookListRazor)
```

**Code**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using BookListRazor.Model;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    namespace BookListRazor.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/News")]
        [ApiController]
        public class NewsController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

            public NewsController(ApplicationDbContext db)
            {
                _db = db;
            }

            //get all news by languageID
            [HttpGet]
           // [Route("api/news/getallnews/{1}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllNews(int langID)
            {
                //var query = await _db.News.OrderByDescending(x => x.NewsDate).Where(x => x.LanguageID == 1 && x.NewsActive==true && x.NewsVisible==true).ToListAsync();

                return Json(new { data = await _db.News.OrderByDescending(x => x.NewsDate).Where(x => x.LanguageID == langID && x.NewsActive == true && x.NewsVisible == true).ToListAsync() });
            }

            //get all news 
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
            {
                return Json(new { data = await _db.News.OrderByDescending(x => x.NewsDate).Where(x => x.LanguageID == 1 && x.NewsActive == true && x.NewsVisible == true).ToListAsync() });
            }


            //get single news by newsID
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingleNews(int id)
            {
                return Json(new { data = await _db.News.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.NewsID == id) });
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change like below:

```
[Route("api/News/[action]")]
[ApiController]
```

Request url like below:

```
//https://localhost:44364/api/news/GetAllNews?langID=1
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllNews(int langID)
{
}

//https://localhost:44364/api/news/GetAll
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{       
}

//https://localhost:44364/api/news/GetSingleNews?id=1
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingleNews(int id)
{       
}
```

Comment: I had done something similar as in my code but forgot to remove top level route which was generating error `[Route("api/news/getallnews/{id}")]`  `[Route("api/news/GetAll")]`  `[Route("api/news/GetSingleNews/{id}")]`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Route] attribute to each method ,

Like this

```
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [Route("api/Test")]
        public IActionResult Index1()
        {
            return Json("Hello World 1");
        }

        [Route("api/Test/Index2")]
        public IActionResult Index2()
        {
            return Json("Hello World 2");
        }
    }
```

Please try it,

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, your solution is more in line with MVC while i was specific to Razor page approach